# Elastic Search (COUNT*) query

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

This seems relatively simple but I'm new to Query DSL. Could yall please help me turn this into code?...

Assuming, I have a 'flight data' set where the dates 1-1-2000 and 1-10-2000 hold many flights (flightId, flightDest, etc.), I want to count* flights between those two dates at intervals of one day.

Thanks

Comment: please share your mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested query would be something like below:

```
GET flight_data_set/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "flight_date": {
        "gte": "2000-01-01",
        "lte": "2000-10-01"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "flight_count_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "flight_date",
        "interval": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! you are a good man. For clarity for anyone reading this, The situation I posed was only analogous to my actual situation, so the above code is not a 1:1 to what I used. Also "Interval" is deprecated and should use "calendar_interval"

Comment: Hey again, If I wanted to also filter the results by a search term such as the field 'message' should contain '[Sucessful login]', could you reply with that version of the code as well? @SaeedNasehi

Comment: for this purpose you need to use bool query like below: 
"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"flight_date":{"gte":"2000-01-01","lte":"2000-10-01"}}},{"match":{"message":"[Sucessful login]"}}]}},"aggs":{"flight_count_per_day":{"date_histogram":{"field":"flight_date","interval":"day"}}}}

Comment: Unfortunately, someone else replied elsewhere with similar code like yours that runs, but both returns 0 hits. 

I feel like it's my fault describing the issue wrong, but it seems very simple. literally all I do, in the Discover visualization of the index, is specify a date range, and type in the search bar "[Successful login]" which is contained in a string field called 'message', then 2 hits are shown. @SaeedNasehi

Comment: It seems like just using the string matching doesn't work either:  `{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "[Successful Login]"
          }
        } 
      ]
    }
  } 
}`

Comment: Your above query does not return results? why did you set size to zero when you want to get data?

Comment: You're correct. My mistake, the above query returns hits with a non-zero size. Then this may be the core issue I'm having - when adding range for 'flight_date' (Date field), nothing is returned: `{
  "size": 4,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {"match": {
            "message": "[Successful login]"
            }
          },
          {"range": {
            "flight_date":{
              "gte":"2000-01-01",
              "lte":"2000-10-01"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  } 
}`

Comment: Sorry for the crap formatting @SaeedNasehi

Comment: No problem. If I understand well, you get result when you don't add match section? and by adding this section you don't received any results? may I see on of your documents in your index?

Comment: I made some changes to the query, and I hate to admit that this whole "flights per day" bs question is just an analogy. I moved this to a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765129/aggregation-with-range-and-match-phrase#68765129) if you'd still like to help. Thanks for the help so far though! @SaeedNasehi